# Submit de valores da view para o controller com post

Tags: html, c#, mvc, view, controller

Sou bastante iniciante em MVC e estava aqui como uma questão:
Na view tenho:

```html
<form id="form1" action="/Jogo/ExecutarAcao" method="post">
 <input type="radio" id="banana" name="opcao" value="banana" onclick="this.RespostaDoJogador.submit();">
    <label for="banana">Banana</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="laranja" name="opcao" value="laranja" onclick="this.RespostaDoJogador.submit();">
    <label for="laranja">Laranja</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="melao" name="opcao" value="melao" onclick="this.RespostaDoJogador.submit();">
    <label for="melao">Melão</label>
    <input type="radio" id="tomate" name="opcao" value="tomate" onclick="this.RespostaDoJogador.submit();">
    <label for="tomate">Tomate</label>
    <button type="submit" form="form1" value="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

E no Controller tenho:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ExecutarAcao(int idJogo, string playerAction, int player1x, int player1y, int player2x, int player2y, int player3x, int player3y, int player4x, int player4y)

{
    Jogo jogoAtual = Repository.CarregarJogo(idJogo);
    jogoAtual.ExecutarAcao(playerAction, player1x, player1y, player2x, player2y, player3x, player3y, player4x, player4y);
    return View("Prototipo", jogoAtual);
}
```

E o meu objetivo é: O valor que é submetido deverá ser o valor atribuído à propriedade `RespostaDoJogador`, que é uma propriedade do Model Jogo.

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia retirar o `onclick="this.RespostaDoJogador.submit();` dos outros componentes da view e **somente** colocar ele no *button*, depois disso você poderia criar uma vetor no qual iria pegar todos os *input radios*, exemplo:

```
var arrayDeRadios = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value;
```

E então você poderia fazer uma verificação usando switch ou if, dessa forma:

```
if(arrayDeRadios[0].checked()){
console.log('O usuário escolheu Banana!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você deveria dizer pelo menos de qual software estamos tratando ou se é puro mesmo, mais o problema ai é que o Onclick impede o envio do formulário diretamente, se você deseja fazer essa verificação do lado do cliente, você deve terminar o serviço no próprio javascript. O OnClick é próprio para este tipo de abordagem, agora, eu acho que se o sistema exige verificação previa, ela deve ser feita no lado do servidor, mais você quem sabe.

Faça a verificação pertinente e finalize fazendo a requisição com ajax, agora isso é no html, eu não sei o que você está construindo em C# que vai precisar de html, então nem vou sugerir código, mais convém analisar e ver se não pode substitui-lo pelo PHP que é uma linguagem universal, de fácil entendimento, você terá maior suporte para resolver os problemas, C# não é difícil mais as pessoas buscam aprender C# quando precisam trabalhar com coisas mais complexas como a construção de um kernel, eu por exemplo não tenho essa necessidade.

Requisição Post com javascript: https://www.devmedia.com.br/ajax-com-jquery-trabalhando-com-requisicoes-assincronas/37141

**Exemplo de ajax**

> **Método jQuery.ajax**
> Na biblioteca jQuery, uma das funções mais utilizadas é a $.ajax(), que, com uma sintaxe bastante simples,
> permite enviar e tratar o resultado de requisições assíncronas. Na
> Listagem 1, temos um exemplo básico de uso desse método, no qual
> enviamos algumas informações via POST para um arquivo PHP.

```
$.ajax({
 method: "POST",
 url: "cadastrar.php",
 data: { nome: "Pedro", email: "pedro@email.com" }
})
```

**Exemplo jquery**

> **Método jQuery.post**
> A função $.post() também é uma forma simplificada
> de $.ajax(), no entanto, dessa vez as requisições são enviadas por
> meio do método HTTP POST. Na Listagem 3 temos um exemplo de uso.

```
$.post("salvar_dados.php", {
    nome : "Maria Fernanda", salario : "3000"
}, function(msg){
    $("#resultado").html(msg);
})
```